# Reuse javascripts from plugins within the theme

Tags: plugins, javascript, slideshow

I am trying to reuse the bxslider javascript that gets installed in a plugin.

The page I am working on has this basic structure:

> SLIDER                            <-- configured  in a plugin
>
> SLIDER OF WOOCOMMERCE OFFERS     <-- list of offers comes from woocommerce
>
> SLIDER                            <-- configured  in a plugin

I am actually using bxslider.
The woocommerce gives me actually a list of offers, so I'd like them to trigger bxslider for them. with a simple

> ```
>  $('.products').bxSlider({
>     });
> ```

So i am trying in the functions.php

> wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery','bxslider'), '20151215', true );

Actually I only get a .bxslider() is not a function javascript ERROR.

I also tried to include bxslider additionally as a javascript including dependencies, but the error stays the same...

Answer (score 0):

> var j = jQuery.noConflict();
>
> ```
>     j(document).ready(function() 
>     {
>        j('.products').bxSlider({
>        });
>
>     });
> ```

Did the trick!
& including bxslider.js in wp_enqueue with jquery dependency before the main